# Factors that affect retain count

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am having difficulty locating a memory leak.  I am using cocos2d.  This is the data area for two classes:

```
@interface Dungeon : CCLayerColor {
    DungeonLevel *aDungeonLevel;
    Player *thePlayer;

    // list of all monster file names
    NSMutableArray *monsterNames;

    // array of how many monsters there are of each monster level
    NSMutableArray *monsterLevels;

    MessageView *theMessageView;

    DungeonDisplay *theDisplay;

    bool processing;

    int currentDungeonLevel;    
}

@interface DungeonDisplay : CCLayerColor {
    NSMutableArray *displayGrid;
    NSMutableArray *displayGrid2;
    NSMutableArray *displayGrid3;
    NSMutableArray *displayGrid4;
    NSMutableArray *dungeonMatrix;
    NSMutableArray *monsterSprites;
    Dungeon *theDungeon;  
    int xdelt;
    int ydelt;
    CGPoint lowerLeft;
    Player *thePlayer;
    CCSprite *playerSprite;
    CCSprite *mSprite1;

    ButtonsLayer *buttonArea;

    double previousTime;
    double currentTime;
    double touchTimePrev;
    bool touchFlag;
    bool processing;
    bool processing2;
    bool animating;
    bool flipSprite;
    bool doIdleAnimation;
    bool isAttacking;
    int firstIteration;
    CGPoint dungeonOriginalPosition;
    CGPoint playerOriginalPosition;
    CGPoint mSprite1Original;
    CGPoint buttonOriginal;
    CCTimer *myTimer;

    // List of Messages
    NSMutableArray *messages;    
    int messageIndex;

    // player transparency level
    int transparency;

    // indicates that walls need to become transparent
    bool needTransparency;

    int pXInc;
    int pYInc;
    int tempx;
    int tempy;

    // debugging variables
    CCLabelTTF *debugLabel1;
    CCLabelTTF *debugLabel2;

    // the Map
    MiniMap *aMap;
}
```

Okay, now the Dungeon object creates the DungeonDisplay object by interacting with another object, DungeonLevel (I don't think it is particularly relevant to figuring out why DungeonDisplay is not deallocated).  This is all the code for creation of the "singleton" DungeonDisplay object:

```
-(void) displayDungeon
{
    if (!theDisplay) {
        theDisplay = [[DungeonDisplay alloc]init];
        [self addChild:theDisplay z:101];
        [theDisplay letTheDungeon:self];    
    }
    else {
        [thePlayer placePC:thePlayer.pCLocation];
        [theDisplay displayStructure];
    }
    theDisplay.visible = true;
    aDungeonLevel.visible = NO;
}
```

For some reason, after addChild (a cocos method) the retain count jumps to 4 (from 1).  "letTheDungeon" has no effect on retain count (as expected).

Comment: Can you provide a little context? What type of object is this being invoked from and what sort of object is `DungeonDisplay`? Am I correct in assuming that `addChild` is a method that you've written (in which case can you share that code with us, too)? When I've seen counts jump up like that, it was generally a result of my adding it to a NSMutableArray/NSMutableDictionary and neglecting to remove it from that structure. But we don't have enough here to diagnose it. I know it's painful, but can you give us more context and more of the related code?

Comment: Is the static analyzer giving you a clean bill of health? Shift-command-B is all it takes to analyze your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers.  The problem is resolved and I again have insignificant leaking.  The problem was with CCTouchDispatcher in the child class, DungeonDisplay.  I changed the code for processing touches to the dungeon class and made some other minor adjustments and everyone dealloc's are being called.

Anyway, its rock solid again.  I moved over a hundred times back and forth and their was no change in allocated memory.  In fact, I'm now cruising at under 70 MB, less than before.

Thanks again, especially for your words of encouragement and support.

Answer (score 7):

**Question:** "I am having difficulty locating a memory leak. ... Does anybody have a comprehensive list of the specific things that increase and decrease retain count?"

**Answer:** Wow, tons of things. Just focusing on what increases retain counts, it includes: adding subviews; pushing/presenting controllers; adding to dictionaries and arrays; any method whose name begins with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`; any `retain` invocations; creating objects in non-ARC code in `viewDidLoad` and neglecting to clean them up in `dealloc`; allocating another new object in one of your pointers in non-ARC code that already is pointing to an item that hasn't yet been released; any core foundation functions with `create` or `copy` in the name; etc. And this probably only scratches the surface. The list of what decreases retain counts is just as long.

No offense, this is unlikely to be a productive route to tracking down a leak. (It's like saying someone was shot in Manhattan, so let's get a list of everyone on the Eastern seaboard with a gun.) I'd suggest you pursue more of a CSI approach:

1. Run your code through the [Xcode static analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH3-SW22). Until you fix all of those issues, there's no point in looking any further. You should get *zero* warnings from your static analysis.
2. Use the profiler tools to [find the leak](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW26). Once you learn how to use that tool, it can often show you precisely which object and line of code is causing a leak, at which point resolution is much easier.
3. Make sure you fully read and understand [Advanced Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). If you're doing anything with core foundation, also check out [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html).
4. If you're not using ARC, start putting in debugging messages that examine the `retainCount` of your various objects.

If you find a piece of code that's leaking, if you can't figure it out, then post the offending code here on StackOverflow (make sure to tell us if it's ARC or not) and we can help you diagnose it further.

I really don't mean to be snarky, but this question, as it stands, is too broad for us to help you (and even if someone theoretically could give you your comprehensive answer, I can't imagine it would be at all helpful to you). Hopefully some of the above tips will point you in the right direction, though.

I seriously get your frustration. That first project where you decide you're going to get serious about tracking down leaks is a painful exercise. You have to master the non-trivial world of Objective-C memory management and learn some pretty complicated tools (the profiler, especially). But once you go through the exercise once in a big project, and master the tools, you'll have that "ah ha" moment, and tracking down memory leaks will become a simple (or at least methodical) process.

Comment: I checked static analyzer and there were no problems (except with cocos libraries).  The leak tool found no sigificant leaks but this was contrary to the allocations tool, which showed that memory IS leaking (leading to my crashes).  I have identified which deallocs are not being called (with NSLogs) but cant figure out why the retain count isn't dropping correctly so it can be called.

Comment: I don't quite get the "except with cocoas libraries" reference. Very rarely you'll find a small leak in existing libraries, but I've never seen a static analyzer warning that was not directly related to my code.

Comment: Also, you say that you're getting leaks leading to crashes. It's rare that a leak leads to a crash (unless you're leaking _a lot_ and future memory allocations fail). Most leaks manifest themselves as slow, annoying reductions in available memory. Crashes are more often the result of over-deallocated items or bad pointers. Turning on [zombies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) can help with that.

Comment: For the first comment: Static analyzer shows which specific .m files (and exactly where also) are having what problems.  The only files for which problems are reported (except one "logic" error which isn't really an error) are CCMenuItem.m, CCSprite.m etc. showing errors like "dead code" and some other strange such beyond my comprehension, but not in any of the .m files or code that I have specifically written.

Comment: For the second: I do believe that it is the memory allocation itself that is causing the crashes: while there are some small memory leaks from the beginning of the program, including in "simple audio engine", a cocos2d module I think, they aren't at all bothersome.  My program acquires 72MB of memory and cruises nicely, until I reach a certain part, where as I move back and forth from "town" to "dungeon" 2-3MB get leaked.  After about 25-35 frolics, the program then crashes and of course, a player could certainly make that number of forays at a sitting, if committed.

Comment: i use this framework for about a year. and almost all of my troubles were by my fault, not cocos2d. and even it's troubles did not cause such memory leaks

Comment: I'm certain this is my error, I just can't figure out what at the moment.  However, cocos2d does, in the sense that static analyzer looks at things, have "errors" (note the quotes).

Comment: @user1437403 By the way, are you using cocos2d v1.0.1?

Comment: I think so - #DEFINE COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00010001 ?

Comment: @user1437403 Yep, that's 1.0.1. I was just confused because I just did a static analysis of 1.0.1 (the latest stable release) and I only saw one trivial (and easily rectified) warning, so I was having trouble reconciling that with your other comment. But it sounds like it's academic at this point. Congrats on tracking it down!

Answer (score 1):

the first that can cause your leak is that you don't release created theDisplay instance. Change your code to

```
if (!theDisplay) 
{
    theDisplay = [[DungeonDisplay alloc]init];
    [self addChild:theDisplay z:101];
    [theDisplay release];  // add this line
    [theDisplay letTheDungeon:self];    
}
```

or

```
if (!theDisplay) 
{
    theDisplay = [[[DungeonDisplay alloc] init] autorelease];  // create autoreleased object
    [self addChild:theDisplay z:101];
    [theDisplay letTheDungeon:self];    
}
```

it will resolve at least one memory issue.

Comment: Thanks. In fact what I do is, at another function in the same class, when getting ready to leave, I [self removeChild:theDisplay] and then [theDisplay release];  I think that's about right, since both the alloc and addchild increase the retain count.

Comment: @user1437403 While I suspect it's unrelated to your original question, I agree with Morion that it's good practice to release (i.e. just reduce the retain count) right up front after `addChild` (either explicitly or through an autorelease). No reason to defer this release and in many cases (though not this one) it can save you headaches. But I see from your other response that you solved your problem. That's great!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this may not be 'scientifically' correct, but sometimes you got to do what you got to do. Use the Instruments Zombies tool as follows. At some place in your code where you KNOW you already have leaked an object, issue [theLeakedObject_ release] as many times as it takes to zombie it out. Then within instruments, you will be able to get a trace of the retain count, which class increases it, and which decreases it, in the order it happens, until obviously you zombie out. You should be able to 'spot' a retainer that should not be there, and take it from there.

ps. as a matter of personal practice, i follow Morion's suggest practice and stick with autorelease allocation pattern, when creating objects that derive from CCNode. Keeps things neat and tidy, and the cleanup:YES process wipes after me very well :). And for any other business class, i specifically retain/release to leave as much room in the autorelease pool for cocos.